# Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error on xCode 6.1 OSX 10.10

Tags: xcode, openframeworks

Hi I have been trying to run some addon examples on openframeworks with my xCode 6.1 and OSX 10.10, however a lot of them have Apple Mach-O Linker (Id) Error.

May I ask if it is the version of my xCode or OSX that don't debug these errors?
Or are there some ways to fix them?

Cheers,
Karen

```
 CompileC /Users/karen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ofxPdTest-agukegtuogdvplfnsnbqnbyyznpk/Build/Intermediates/ofxPdTest.build/Debug/ofxPdTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bonk~.o /Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c normal x86_64 c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
    cd /Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/apps/myApps/ofxPdTest
    export LANG=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x c -arch x86_64 -fmessage-length=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit=0 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-return-type -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-variable -Wno-unused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wno-constant-conversion -Wno-int-conversion -Wno-bool-conversion -Wno-enum-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk -fasm-blocks -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -g -mssse3 -Wno-sign-conversion -I/Users/karen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ofxPdTest-agukegtuogdvplfnsnbqnbyyznpk/Build/Intermediates/ofxPdTest.build/Debug/ofxPdTest.build/ofxPdTestDebug.hmap -I/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/apps/myApps/ofxPdTest/bin/include -I../../../libs/openFrameworks -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/3d -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/app -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/communication -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/events -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/gl -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/graphics -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/math -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/sound -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/types -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/utils -I../../../libs/openFrameworks/video -I../../../libs/poco/include -I../../../libs/freetype/include -I../../../libs/freetype/include/freetype2 -I../../../libs/fmodex/include -I../../../libs/glew/include -I../../../libs/FreeImage/include -I../../../libs/tess2/include -I../../../libs/cairo/include/cairo -I../../../libs/rtAudio/include -I../../../libs/glfw/include -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/cpp -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/libpd_wrapper -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/libpd_wrapper/util -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~ -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/choice -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/fiddle~ -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/loop~ -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/lrshift~ -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/pd~ -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/pique -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/sigmund~ -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/stdout -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/src -I../../../addons/ofxPd-master/src -I/Users/karen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ofxPdTest-agukegtuogdvplfnsnbqnbyyznpk/Build/Intermediates/ofxPdTest.build/Debug/ofxPdTest.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -I/Users/karen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ofxPdTest-agukegtuogdvplfnsnbqnbyyznpk/Build/Intermediates/ofxPdTest.build/Debug/ofxPdTest.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/apps/myApps/ofxPdTest/bin -F/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/apps/myApps/ofxPdTest/../../../libs/glut/lib/osx -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/karen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ofxPdTest-agukegtuogdvplfnsnbqnbyyznpk/Build/Intermediates/ofxPdTest.build/Debug/ofxPdTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bonk~.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/karen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ofxPdTest-agukegtuogdvplfnsnbqnbyyznpk/Build/Intermediates/ofxPdTest.build/Debug/ofxPdTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bonk~.dia -c /Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c -o /Users/karen/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ofxPdTest-agukegtuogdvplfnsnbqnbyyznpk/Build/Intermediates/ofxPdTest.build/Debug/ofxPdTest.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/bonk~.o

/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:191:5: error: unknown type name 't_float'; did you mean 'float'?
    t_float *g_invec;           /* new input samples */
    ^~~~~~~
    float
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:297:39: warning: implicit declaration of function 'getbytes' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    t_filterbank *b = (t_filterbank *)getbytes(sizeof(*b));
                                      ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:297:23: warning: cast to 't_filterbank *' (aka 'struct _filterbank *') from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    t_filterbank *b = (t_filterbank *)getbytes(sizeof(*b));
                      ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:307:16: warning: cast to 't_filterkernel *' (aka 'struct _filterkernel *') from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    b->b_vec = (t_filterkernel *)getbytes(nfilters * sizeof(*b->b_vec));
               ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:329:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'post' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            post("bonk~: only using %d filters (ran past Nyquist)", i+1);
            ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:346:13: warning: cast to 'float *' from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
            (float *)getbytes(2 * sizeof(float) * filterpoints);
            ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:392:44: warning: using the result of an assignment as a condition without parentheses [-Wparentheses]
    else for (b2 = bonk_filterbanklist; b3 = b2->b_next; b2 = b3)
                                        ~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:392:44: note: place parentheses around the assignment to silence this warning
    else for (b2 = bonk_filterbanklist; b3 = b2->b_next; b2 = b3)
                                           ^
                                        (              )
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:392:44: note: use '==' to turn this assignment into an equality comparison
    else for (b2 = bonk_filterbanklist; b3 = b2->b_next; b2 = b3)
                                           ^
                                           ==
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:400:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'freebytes' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            freebytes(b->b_vec[i].k_stuff,
            ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:423:22: warning: cast to 'float *' from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
        g->g_inbuf = (float *)getbytes(npoints * sizeof(float));
                     ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:432:21: warning: cast to 't_template *' (aka 'struct template *') from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
    x->x_template = (t_template *)getbytes(0);
                    ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:445:26: warning: implicit declaration of function 'clock_getsystime' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    x->x_learndebounce = clock_getsystime();
                         ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:475:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 't_atom'
    t_atom at[MAXNFILTERS], *ap, at2[3];
    ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:494:57: warning: implicit declaration of function 'qrsqrt' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            float intensity = *pp = (power > 0 ? 100. * qrsqrt(qrsqrt(power)) : 0);
                                                        ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:525:27: warning: implicit declaration of function 'clock_gettimesince' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            double msec = clock_gettimesince(lasttime);
                          ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:540:51: warning: implicit declaration of function 't_resizebytes' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                    x->x_template = (t_template *)t_resizebytes(x->x_template,
                                                  ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:540:37: warning: cast to 't_template *' (aka 'struct template *') from smaller integer type 'int' [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
                    x->x_template = (t_template *)t_resizebytes(x->x_template,
                                    ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:604:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SETFLOAT' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    SETFLOAT(at2, nfit);
    ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:604:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'at2'
    SETFLOAT(at2, nfit);
             ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:605:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'at2'
    SETFLOAT(at2+1, vel);
             ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:606:14: error: use of undeclared identifier 'at2'
    SETFLOAT(at2+2, temperature);
             ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:607:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'outlet_list' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    outlet_list(x->x_cookedout, 0, 3, at2);
    ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:607:20: error: no member named 'x_cookedout' in 'struct _bonk'
    outlet_list(x->x_cookedout, 0, 3, at2);
                ~  ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:614:21: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ap'
        for (i = 0, ap = at, pp2 = pp; i < nfilters;
                    ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:614:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'at'
        for (i = 0, ap = at, pp2 = pp; i < nfilters;
                         ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:615:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ap'
            i++, ap++, pp2++)
                 ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:617:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ap'
            ap->a_type = A_FLOAT;
            ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:617:26: error: use of undeclared identifier 'A_FLOAT'
            ap->a_type = A_FLOAT;
                         ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:618:13: error: use of undeclared identifier 'ap'
            ap->a_w.w_float = *pp2;
            ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:620:25: error: no member named 'g_outlet' in 'struct _insig'
        outlet_list(gp->g_outlet, 0, nfilters, at);
                    ~~  ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:712:17: warning: implicit declaration of function 'clock_delay' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
                clock_delay(x->x_clock, 0);
                ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:712:32: error: no member named 'x_clock' in 'struct _bonk'
                clock_delay(x->x_clock, 0);
                            ~  ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:736:24: error: no member named 'x_clock' in 'struct _bonk'
        clock_delay(x->x_clock, 0);
                    ~  ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:741:8: error: unknown type name 't_int'
static t_int *bonk_perform(t_int *w)
       ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:741:28: error: unknown type name 't_int'
static t_int *bonk_perform(t_int *w)
                           ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:766:17: error: use of undeclared identifier 't_float'; did you mean 'float'?
                t_float *in1 = gp->g_invec + onset;
                ^~~~~~~
                float
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:799:33: error: unknown type name 't_signal'
static void bonk_dsp(t_bonk *x, t_signal **sp)
                                ^
/Users/karen/Dropbox/OpenFrameworks/of_v0.8.4_osx_release/addons/ofxPd-master/libs/libpd/pure-data/extra/bonk~/bonk~.c:809:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'dsp_add' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    dsp_add(bonk_perform, 2, x, n);
    ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
18 warnings and 20 errors generated.
```

Comment: Can you give us the logs for the Mach-O Linker errors that you receive?

Comment: Is it all the examples in ofxPd that give you this error? And do you have the newest version of ofxPd?

Comment: Hello, I am just trying to run the example.xcodeproj using the latest version of ofxPd.